# Express redirecting doesn't change req.url

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a route that redirects upon successful login

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  if(req.body.password === Server.cfg.auth.userPass) {
    req.session.user = {nick: req.body.username, pass: req.body.password}
    res.redirect('/chat')
  } else {
    res.render('user/login', { locals: { error: 'Invalid password' } })
  }
})
```

The redirect seems to work as the page is refreshed with the correctly rendered jade file. However, the url still says /login and my pageTitle variable (being set through template vars) does not change either. If I refresh the page after the redirect, everything changes to the way it should be. It is only after the redirect that it does not change.

Comment: Shouldn't /chat be wrapped in quotes? res.redirect("/chat") ?

Comment: yesh, thank you, typo on entering the question :)

Comment: Can you try putting `req.method = 'GET';` before res.redirect? I know I've had a similar problem with redirecting on a POST route and this was a bug in Express at that moment.

Comment: That solution had no effect. Still not changing the req.url after the redirect. It's weird because when I console.log req.url in my route middleware it echoes as it should be.

Comment: Can you give make a small github repo with the code above, the view and everything needed (simplified of course into 1-2 files) so I can debug locally?

Comment: I got up this morning, restarted the server and all is well, weird

Answer (score 1):

This has got to be a pretty common mix up for folks trying to deal with ajax redirects coming from a server controlled development background. My example shows what happens if authorization fails, slightly different; but you can use the same concept of intercepting the response and checking status, etc., and let the client JavaScript do the redirect.

My client code is actually a backbone model but in turn is calling jquery's ajax like:

```
model.save({ error:function...
```

**Server**

```
function requiresLogin(req, res, next) {  
    if(req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        //res.redirect('/sessions/new?redir=' + req.url); // won't work
        res.send("Unauthorized", 403); // send 403 http status
    }
}
```

Client

```
  // Assumes you can get http status from response
  error: function(resp, status, xhr)...
      if(resp.status === 403) {
          window.location = '/sessions/new'; // optionally put a redirLastPage=somewhere
      }
```

This works as desired for me. I'd also suggest googling ajax post redirects to see why this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a jQuery problem. At least it was for me. You can override it with rel=external. More info at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html.